# Сoncatenation returns more elements than it should

Tags: haskell

I need get neighbours of cells on 1D closed field

for example:

neighbours [1,2,3,4,5,-1] (6 elements)

must return [[-1,1,2],[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,-1],[5,-1,1]] (6 elements)

my code of neighbours

```
neighbours :: [a] -> [[a]]
neighbours l = concat [[[last l, head l, last $ take 2 l]], neighbours' l, [[l !! (length l - 2), last l, head l]]] where
    neighbours' :: [a] -> [[a]]
    neighbours' (a:b:c:xs) = [a, b, c]:neighbours (b:c:xs)
    neighbours' _ = []

main = print $ neighbours [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

returns [[4,1,2],[1,2,3],[4,2,3],[2,3,4],[4,3,4],[3,4,3],[3,4,2],[3,4,1]] (8 elements), but expected [[4,1,2],[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,1]] (4 elements)

if I comment neighbours' l it return
[[4,1,2],[3,4,1]] as expected (2 elements)

if you leave only neighbours' l it return
[[1,2,3],[2,3,4]] as expected (2 elements)

2+2=4, but in this case for some reason it is 8

why it happens?

P.s.

neighbours' create middle of list

neighbours' [1,2,3,4,5,-1] == [[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5],[4,5,-1]]

[last l, head l, last $ take 2 l] create head of list [-1,1,2]

[l !! (length l - 2), last l, head l] create last element of list [5,-1,1]

Comment: Your code is quite mysterious because you haven't given any context about what it's supposed to *mean*. Please explain in the body of your question. Using `head` and `last` and `!!` tends to make it even harder to guess your intent.

Comment: Desired result can be obtained like this: `neighbors xs = let k = length xs  in  (drop (k-1) $ take (k+k-1) $ map (take 3) (tails (cycle xs)))`

Comment: @dfeuer I added information about goals of the code and it's components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is somewhat hard to grasp because your two functions, `neighbour` and `neighbour'`, are *mutually* recursive, which is sort of unusual.

The key line in your code is:

```
neighbours' (a:b:c:xs) = [a, b, c] : neighbours (b:c:xs)
```

If we assume that this is **NOT** intentional, and you just meant to write:

```
neighbours' (a:b:c:xs) = [a, b, c] : neighbours' (b:c:xs)
-----------------------------------------------+---------
```

then the code works as you seem to expect.

Note that having long (over 80 characters) lines of code makes the thing very difficult to debug.

**Suggested code:**

```
{-#  LANGUAGE  ScopedTypeVariables  #-}
{-#  LANGUAGE  ExplicitForAll       #-}

import qualified  Data.List  as  L

neighbours :: [a] -> [[a]]
neighbours l = concat [
                         [[last l, head l, last $ take 2 l]],
                         neighbours' l,
                         [[l !! (length l - 2), last l, head l]]
                      ]
  where
    neighbours' :: [a] -> [[a]]
    neighbours' (a:b:c:xs) = [a, b, c] : neighbours' (b:c:xs)
    neighbours' _ = []


-- neighbour is British English, neighbor is US English
neighbors :: [a] -> [[a]]
neighbors xs =
    take count $ drop  (count-1)  allTriplets  -- section of infinite list
      where
        count        =  length xs
        allTriplets  =  map  (take 3)  (L.tails (cycle xs))  -- raw material


main :: IO ()
main = do
    print $ "res1 = " ++ (show $ neighbours [1, 2, 3, 4])
    print $ "res2 = " ++ (show $ neighbors  [1, 2, 3, 4])
```

**Program output:**

```
"res1 = [[4,1,2],[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,1]]"
"res2 = [[4,1,2],[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,1]]"
```

Comment: I think you can do it more easily without `tails`. `zip3 (drop (count-1) cycled) xs (drop 1 cycled)`

Comment: Well, `tails`  is relatively cheap, but nice idea, thanks. Just have to convert tuple to list in the end.

Comment: That was just a sketch. You'd actually use `zipWith3 (\a b c -> [a,b,c])`.